Colissimo REST API keep sending me bad request
I try to generate a Label from Colissimo with his REST API but when I try to send a post request I keep getting bad request,
The urls I got from the support :

https://ws.colissimo.fr/sls-ws/SlsServiceWSRest/2.0/generateLabel

here's my service :
      async generateLabel(data: Label) {   
        const url: string =
          'https://ws.colissimo.fr/sls-ws/SlsServiceWSRest/2.0/generateLabel';
        const labelData = labelBuilder(data);
        const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          apikey: process.env.APIKEY,
        };
        try {
          const responseAxios = await axios.post(url, labelData, { headers });    
          return responseAxios.data;
        } catch (error) {
          return error;
        }
      }

And here is the data from the colissimo's documentation, I send:
{
    contractNumber: process.env.COLISSIMO_LOGIN,
    password: process.env.COLISSIMO_PASSWORD,
    outputFormat: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      outputPrintingType: 'PDF_A4_300dpi',
      dematerialized: false,
      returnType: '',
      printCODDocument: 1,
    },
    letter: {
      service: {
        productCode: 'DOM',
        depositDate: '2099-11-23',
        mailBoxPicking: false,
        transportationAmount: 1040,
        totalAmount: 1222,
        orderNumber: 123456,
        commercialName: 'nom du commercial',
        returnTypeChoice: 2,
      },
      parcel: {
        weight: 2,
        nonMachinable: false,
        COD: 0,
        CODAmount: 0,
      },
      sender: {
        senderParcelRef: 'ref sender',
        address: {
          companyName: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzsener comp',
          lastName: 'dupont',
          firstName: 'fred',
          line0: 'line0',
          line1: 'line1',
          line2: 'line2',
          line3: 'line3',
          countryCode: 'MC',
          city: 'paris',
          zipCode: 98000,
          phoneNumber: '0100000000',
          mobileNumber: '0600000000',
          doorCode1: '',
          doorCode2: '',
          email: 'yy@k.fr',
          intercom: '',
          language: 'FR',
        },
      },
      addressee: {
        codeBarForReference: false,
        serviceInfo: 'service info',
        promotionCode: 4444,
        address: {
          companyName: 'test site',
          lastName: 'martin',
          firstName: 'alain',
          line0: 'line0dest',
          line1: 'line1dest',
          line2: 'line2dest',
          line3: 'line3dest',
          countryCode: 'FR',
          city: 'paris',
          zipCode: 75015,
          phoneNumber: '0100000000',
          mobileNumber: '0600000000',
          doorCode1: 'EEE',
          doorCode2: 44444,
          email: '',
          intercom: '',
          language: 'FR',
        },
      },
    },
  };

